# Diameters and Circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I have a question (given by a teacher) that looks really easy but then when I thought about it, couldn't find a way to find the answer.  It is a proof  question relating to diameters:

**Prove that any two diameters are congruent, and that each diameter is twice as long as each radius.**

It seems like common sense, but I can't think of a way to prove it.

Besides this, I also have another question (that I stumbled upon i my reference book) about circles that I could not figure out:

**If one chord is a perpendicular bisector of a different chord, then the first chord is a diameter**

I think there must be a property relating the center of a circle and the perpendicular bisector of  any chord, but I am not sure where to start with this problem.

Any help or hints would be very nice :)

Thank you.

Comment: **Hint:** Two diameters intersect each other on the center and then you can consider two triangles. Note the congruent angles opposite by the vertices.

Comment: I would think that it is the definition of "circle" that any two radii are congruent, and from there the facts about diameters follow.

Comment: @Sigur  Doing that we can prove that the 2 triangles are congruent.  What next?

Comment: @PaulFilch, they are congruent and isosceles since their sides are the circle radius. So you'll have congruent diameters.

Comment: @Sigur  Oh, didn't realize they were isosceles.  Any hints on the 2nd question

Comment: For the second, remember that any point on the first chord is equidistant of the end points of the second one and that the center of the circle also has this property.

Comment: @Sigur Here is the proof I have come up with:  

As the first chord is a perpendicular bisector, it follows that all points on the first chord are equidistant to the endpoints of the second chord.  The center of the circle also has this property and thus the center lies on the first chord.  Finally, by the definition of a diameter, it follows that the first chord is a diameter of the circle.  

Is there anything more to add?

Comment: To be true, all you have to prove (or use) is that the perpendicular line trough the middle point is exactly the set of points equidistant to the end points. It is a locus.

Comment: Okay there is a theorem in my book proving that so I'll use it.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint for first part: Consider two diameters on a circle, of length $a$ and $b$. Since a diameter is a chord of maximum length, diameter $b$ is greater than or equal to all other possible chord lengths, including $a$. Similarly diameter $a$ is greater than or equal tochord $b$. But $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ together imply $a=b$. Hence, any two diameters have the same length, hence any two diameters are congruent.

To show that this maximum chord length is $2r$, you need to show that chords which go through the center are longer than chords which don't.

Comment: I think I got the first part thanks to Sigur.  Any hints on the second question?

Answer (score 0):

The proof is as follows.

Join FA,FD,FB.
As F is the center, FA=FB.
Also, as D bisects AB, we have DA=DB.
As FD is common, then from Triangle Side-Side-Side Equality, △ADF=△BDF.

In particular, ∠ADF=∠BDF; both are right angles

Thus, by definition, F lies on the perpendicular bisector of AB.
Hence the result.